# Javascript shorthand to convert a Null into a value

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I'm building from about 25 elements, such as

```
this.iCite_Data = [
  {id: 1, label: 'PMID', value: (data["pmid"]), group:0,secondary:"PubMed Identifier"},  
  {id: 2, label: 'Expected Citations Rate', value: (data["expected_citations_per_year"]).toFixed(2),group:2, secondary:"Citations per year"}
];
```

If the `data["expected_citations_per_year"]` is `null` this code will throw an error because it is trying `toFixed(2)`.  I need to build this object with about 25 elements so I'm looking for some tight code.  Is there an inline code solution and still retain the fixed 2 if it is not `null`? Would a conditional operator handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to provide a value of `0` if `data["expected_citations_per_year"]` is `undefined` or `null`:

```js
const data = {
  "pmid": 12345,
  //"expected_citations_per_year": 1
}

var iCite_Data = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'PMID',
    value: (data["pmid"]),
    group: 0,
    secondary: "PubMed Identifier"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Expected Citations Rate',
    value:
      (data["expected_citations_per_year"] ?? 0).toFixed(2),
    group: 2,
    secondary: "Citations per year"
  }
];

console.log(iCite_Data);
```

This operator is supported by [~88% of browsers in use globally](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: You could also use `data["expected_citations_per_year"] || 0).toFixed(2)` if you wanted to use *node* < 14 or older browsers

Comment: esqew Works great-- Thank you  Carl I appreciate you input also